# Missing Rigify Buttons Tab!

Tags: rigify

I am attempting to rig for the first time, and I wanted to try out the Rigify Add-on. I have looked up many different tutorials, but I cant seem to solve my problem:

I went  to generate my rig, but for some reason, not even the Rigify Buttons tab will show up! Is there anything I can do to fix this? I am also using the latest (2.76) version of Blender, so maybe there's a different and/or easier way now? Please help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

- Rigify is an add on. Install it.
- Change the window type to User Preferences as above.
- Search or find the Rigify add on.
- Check the box next to the little man.
- Change the window back to the previous .. perhaps 3D View.
- Begin Using.