# Rigify Button missing (v 2.77)

Tags: rigify

Used Rigify to rig my model and like it a lot.  However, the Rigify Button/Generate does not appear in any mode, including Object mode so that's not the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Rigify Buttons Tab!](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45036/missing-rigify-buttons-tab)

Answer (score 1):

Rigify is an Add-on.

It has to be enabled. Open the system preferences

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>

And enable Rigify

[image]

If you want the addon to be enabled permanently press on the Save User Settings.

Comment: I have done those steps.  It was already Enabled and User Settings were saved. Still doesn't appear.

Comment: Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: Frustrating to have your rig ready to render but have no Rigify Generate button, and no one seems to know the fix?  Surely others have encountered this using v 2.77?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers